# How to work around limitation in io:setopts([{echo, false}]) with io:getline/1

Tags: erlang, stdout

I am trying to put a password prompt in my app and am using `io:get_line/1`, which writes the characters to stdout they are typed. My app is running as an escript app, built by rebar.

Following the documentation, I am trying to do `io:setopts([{echo, false}])` which returns `{error,enotsup}` and does not successfully turn of the echoing.

I'm worried about opening `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` directly because it is not multi-platform.

Any recommendations on how to work around the limitation of `io:setopts` with `echo`, or know of an alternate way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no easy way to do that. Escripts use old version of io server. Neither `io:setopts([{echo, false}])` nor `io:get_password()` work from escript. There was a topic about it on [Erlang mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-November/062804.html). The best solutions is to use bash script for reading password:

```
read -s password
./escript $password
```

where escript is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript

main([Password]) ->
    io:format(" -> ~p\n", [Password]).
```

Comment: Well that is disappointing, thanks for the response. Any idea if this is an open item in a tracker somewhere to address?